# Replace specific text using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Here is a text in html

```
...now have strategies to |lead our company| successfully...
```

and here is what I want using jquery

```
...now have strategies to <strong>lead our company</strong> successfully...
```

I tried

```
jQuery(function(){ 
   jQuery('.quotes').each(function() { 
     console.log(jQuery(this).text()); 
     var text = jQuery(this).text().replace(/[|]/g,"<strong>"); 
     var texts = jQuery(text).replace(/[|]/g,"</strong>");
     jQuery(this).html(text); 
   }); 

});
```

Comment: Did you really have | symbol in your string?

Comment: Yes, I have this symbol in the string

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I did but it makes the bold string up to the end of the string. not the string in between the symbol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a regex with a global modifier like this:

```
\|([^|]+)\|
```

with a replacement of:

```
'<strong>$1</strong>'
```

The `|` is a special character in regex and can be escaped (`\|`) to refer to it literally.

The `([^|]+)` captures a group containing at least one non `|` character.

```js
var text = '...now have strategies to |lead our company| successfully...';
text = text.replace(/\|([^|]+)\|/g, '<strong>$1</strong>');
console.log(text);
```

Comment: This is a better answer than mine as yours will work when there's multiple `|...|` sections in the text.